# global flight network (with number of pessengers per year) dataset

Tags: dataset

Is there such a global flight network dataset that gives you:

1. flight route (the connection between each airports or cities by some flight company)
2. the number of passengers (per year) taking each route.

In other words the dataset is a directed flight graph with passenger volume as the edge weight.

The closest thing I can find is [OpenFlights](https://openflights.org/data.html#route) route data.

Comment: I'm curious if you ended up finding anything?

Comment: You might have more luck on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/